# Text wrap labels in QGIS 3.2

Tags: qgis, labeling, text

In QGIS 3.2, I want to show text labels on a map that are coming from a polygon attribute - easy enough. But I want to have the flexibility to set the wrap text position in a certain space, not just at all spaces - as the text now looks ugly in that layout with a word on each line. Is there any way that can be done? e.g., make the *only* text wrap after the word "Regis" in this example: "Newtown Regis and Seckington".

Comment: For your example, you could try the expression in the _Label with_ textbox: `regexp_replace("fieldName",'Regis ', 'Regis\n')`

Comment: I can't seem to find the "Label with" option that you mention in the QGIS label controls of the polygon dataset, when going in via Properties -> Label ->

Comment: It's the property where you select which field you want to label. Instead of typing the name of the field, you can use an expression.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the names of the other 30 or 40 odd polygons, as they all have different names for each. I suppose Ideally I'm need a way to have full control over labels associated with the polygons that are fully editable - in ArcGIS I would create an annotation layer and then be able to edit the labels which would be "locked" to the map.